# SF book from the early 1980s (or earlier): Humans hunted by shapeshifting aliens

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens, shape-shifter

I remember this book from High School.  It was not one of the classics, but would love to re-read it.  Plot involved a game with humans (on earth) being hunted by a set of shapeshifting aliens (who paid to hunt the people).  Think of it as a mashup of Robert Sheckley "10th Victim" meets "Predator."  One of the "hunters' used an Uzi to kill its prey.  May have had an element of reality gameshows.

Comment: This reminds me a bit of "The Symbiotes" by James H Schmitz - there are a set of alien symbiotes, three different ones including a shapeshifter and a possesing entity, that make a sort of game out of some people's lives (for profit), and hunt another couple of people through the grounds of a private asteroid.  Other elements don't fit so well, though.

Answer (score 3):

If this is the book I'm thinking of it was part of a two book series. People thought they'd won some sort of contest but were double crossed and taken to be hunted by the aliens. One was an Idi Amin-style African strongman and his kind of wimpy son.  OK, I found it.  The book was either "The Hunters" or "The Treasure Hunters".  Both books by Burt Wetanson and Thomas Hoobler. From Amazon (The Hunters)

[image]

> "A mysterious couple arrives in a small Montana town and offers its residents a trip to Paradise. Instead...they get a taste of hell on earth."

[image]